# Moodle - Disable from creating News Forum on Course Creation

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to the PHP LMS Framework, `Moodle`. I have seen a default feature of `moodle`, of creating News Forum, when the course gets created. Whereas, I wish to suppress this feature, I don't want News Forums.

What I did, was I changed the visibility flag for `forum` to `0` zero, in `mdl_modules` table. This was not reflecting forum in my `Create Activity` list but created a News Forum, but is creating a News Forum in `mdl_course_modules`.

How can I stop this Forum Creation.? Is there any settings associated with this.?

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot easier to achieve than you might expect. When creating the new course, simply set "News items to show" (in the "Appearance" section of the config form) to 0 (zero). The News forum (and the Latest news block) will not be created.

You can also make this the default setting for newly created courses by setting it in the Site administration -> Courses -> Course default settings form (/admin/settings.php?section=coursesettings).

Answer (score 0):

You can set default blocks in config.php

ex:

```
$CFG->defaultblocks_topics = 'online_users,progress,activity_modules,search_forums,calendar_upcoming,course_list:news_items,recent_activity';
```

where course_list:news_items = block and forum news